# Extra Condition within Select Statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have a select statement whose condition is based on the first letter/digit of a cell. My problem is I have cells whose values can fall on two different Cases. For example  cells with 247L and 250L will return  a "B",I however want them to execute on different conditions. I would like to nest a select case or an IF statement that will only return a "B" for all cells that start with 2 and return a different value if they are above 250L.

```
Option Compare Text
Sub Main()
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    'Loop to find cells with value to use
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To FinalRow
    'Output results to cells and columns
    Cells(i, 14).Value = mBlineCTG(i) & findShpc(i)
    Cells(i, 16).Value = findTrainId(i)
    'Write Column Headers
    Range("N1").Value = "SH_CAT"
    Range("P1").Value = "TRAIN_ID"
    Next
End Sub

Public Function mBlineCTG(i As Long)
Dim cRange 
Dim shpCt As String
 ' determine category by first digit of cell
    Select Case UCase(Left(Cells(i, 13).Value, 1))
        Case "D"
        shpCt = "D"
        Case "0"
            shpCt = "V"
        Case "1", "R", "E", "F"
               shpCt = "S"
        Case "I"
            shpCt = "I"
        Case "2" 
           Select case cRange   'checking for range within, doesnt work
               case 200L to 249L
                 shpCt = "B"
               case else
                 shpct = "F"
           end select   
        Case "3"
            shpCt = "F"
        Case Else
            shpCt = ""
    End Select

   mBlineCTG = shpCt

End Function
```

Comment: cRange has not been set to anything, Therefore it is empty and will never equal anyone of the choices.

Comment: @Scott am a novice with VBA, should I set my cRange to say 200L to 249L? or did you mean to set as Boolean?

Comment: crange needs to be either a range or the value of a cell.  Most likely `set crange = cells(i,13)`.  Then change the second select statement to `Select Case Left(cRange,Len(cRange)-1)`  and the case statement to `case 200 to 249`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put an If in each of the possible Case statements... unless I'm missing something in your question? Hope this helps.

Comment: No the reason that the second case statement does nothing is that the variable cRange is not assigned a value, and therefore there is nothing to test..